# SQL select statement with and SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I was trying to write a SQL select statement with a nested `and` to obtain some data:

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE WORK.TEMP AS

SELECT DISTINCT

(CASE WHEN t1.TYPE_OF_SALE = 'Cake' AND t1.ADD_ON_FLAG = 0 THEN 'Arrangements'

WHEN t1.TYPE_OF_SALE = 'Cake' AND t1.ADD_ON_FLAG = 1 THEN 'Add-ons'

ELSE 'Direct' END) SALE_TYPE, #ERROR IN THIS LINE


(t1.UNIT_PRICE+t1.SERVICE_CHARGE_AMT) AS TOTAL_VAL

FROM WORK.FB_ORDERS t1

ORDER BY SALE_TYPE;

QUIT;
```

I for some reason get an error in my first line, is it not possible to use `and` with a `case statement`?

```
Error Message:
Error 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !,!!,&...
```

This error exists right at the end of the `case statement`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Your query looks fine, I'm not familiar with SAS, but you can definitely use `AND` in `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that SAS requires `as` for defining a column alias:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.TEMP AS
    SELECT DISTINCT (CASE WHEN t1.TYPE_OF_SALE = 'Cake' AND t1.ADD_ON_FLAG = 0 THEN 'Arrangements'
                          WHEN t1.TYPE_OF_SALE = 'Cake' AND t1.ADD_ON_FLAG = 1 THEN 'Add-ons'
                          ELSE 'Direct'
                      END) as SALE_TYPE,
                    (t1.UNIT_PRICE+t1.SERVICE_CHARGE_AMT) AS TOTAL_VAL
    FROM WORK.FB_ORDERS t1
    ORDER BY SALE_TYPE;

QUIT;
```

SAS allows other expressions after a column, such as FORMAT, so I think the `as` is needed to prevent ambiguity in the expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You need an AS:

```
proc sql;
select distinct
(case when age<14 and sex='F' then "Young Girl"
      when age<14 and sex='M' then "Young Boy"
      else "Other" end) as type from sashelp.class;
      quit;
```